# How do you interpret the Cluster Chain Run in an NTFS MFT record?

Tags: filesystems, ntfs, hard-drive-recovery, mft

For mostly academic reasons, I've been learning how to interpret the Cluster Chain Run from the Data Attribute Block from an MFT Record from a NTFS volume.

I watched a [video](https://youtu.be/GHLwl77b36s?t=774) that walks through an example. Here's the example:

Flags | Cluster count | First cluster
`41` `02` `f8 38 c7 01`
`21` `02` `c5 07`
`31` `04` `83 43 01`
`21` `08` `c0 fc`
`31` `10` `44 0b 00`
`31` `01` `f7 ef f9`
`21` `1f` `c6 e7`
`21` `10` `6b 28`
`31` `01` `00 52 e4`

Now, the video shows some disk editing software that is interpreting the hex output. This is helpful, because the author of the video completely skips over at least 3 fundamental concepts:

1. The "First cluster" field is cumulative. Easy enough to figure out if you use a calculator.
2. The "First cluster" field is a signed integer, so that it can navigate backwards on the disk. This was trickier to figure out, but I got it.
3. The third completely ignored concept is when the the least significant byte of the "First cluster" field is zeros. **Since these fields are interpreted little-endian, and since this is a flexible-length field (the flags say how many bytes), then why would you have leading zeros?**

So, here's how I calculate it.

Flags | Cluster count | First cluster
`41` `02` `f8 38 c7 01`
2 clusters starting at cluster # 29,833,464
`21` `02` `c5 07`
2 more clusters starting 1,989 from 29,833,464, which is cluster # 29,835,453
`31` `04` `83 43 01`
4 more clusters starting 82,819 from 29,835,453, which is cluster # 29,918,272
`21` `08` `c0 fc`
8 more clusters starting 832 *earlier than* 29,918,272, which is cluster # 29,917,440
`31` `10` `44 0b 00`
16 more clusters starting 2,884 from 29,917,440, which is cluster # 29,920,324
This is where my math deviates from their math. **They say cluster # 29,840,452. I need help here.**
`31` `01` `f7 ef f9`
`21` `1f` `c6 e7`
`21` `10` `6b 28`
`31` `01` `00 52 e4`

How does the math work when you have leading zeros in one of the fields?  I also have a separate example where the leading zeros are in the "Cluster count" field, not the "First cluster" field; is that treated any different?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 31 10 44 0b 00, 16 more clusters starting 2,884 from 29,917,440, which
> is cluster # 29,920,324 This is where my math deviates from their
> math. They say cluster # 29,840,452. I need help

It's not your math that's wrong, the guy demonstrating in the video is wrong or at least ignores an important issue:

He cheats a little and he just reads the values from the *interpreted values* from the column on the left as if he's converting the values he highlights 'on the fly'.

But his handy *already* converted values take into account the *update sequence array* which he fails to mention and point out.

**Update Sequence Array and fixup value**

The run you're having a problem with is *not* `31 10 44 0b 00`. If we look closely at his sequence of bytes in the video we see the last two bytes of the run are the last two bytes in a 512 byte sector:

[image]

Therefore 0b 00 are *not* the two bytes that belong to this run, it is the 'fixup'. To get the actual values you need to read them from the so called 'Update Sequence Array' for which the offset is stored at byte offset 4 in the MFT entry (usually 0x30).

At offset 0x30 you'll see the bytes 0b 00 (the fixup value), next two bytes will be original values of last two bytes of first sector of the MFT entry, next 2 the ones for the next sector.

I'll Illustrate using a MFT entry from my drive:

[image]

So `31 10 44 0b 00` is actually `31 10 44 xx xx` where you replace xx with the bytes from the update sequence array, then you do your math.

The purpose of fixup values is detecting corruption. So as soon as we read the MFT entry we check fixup value and compare it to last 2 bytes of each sector, they should match, if not the sector is corrupt. To then actually work with the entry we need to correct fixup value with values from the update sequence array first.

> Since these fields are interpreted little-endian, and since this is a
> flexible-length field (the flags say how many bytes), then why would
> you have leading zeros?

TBH, I haven't got the foggiest idea. At the time I was studying this, I did so for writing a NTFS file recovery program (aside, I re-discovered it's source code very recently and recompiled to see if would still run. [It did](https://youtu.be/Ag5g4u0VP-w)!)

Anyway, point is, when I figured out data runs I never looked at those runs very closely again because I wrote code to handle them.

But yes, you are right. Again I turned to my own hard drive and got this entry:

[image]

So we get:

```
31 - 38 - 12 39 09 
43 - 76 2B 01 - 42 77 BB 03 
43 - A7 82 01 - 91 14 D6 00 <<
33 - DC D1 01 - 5B 2B FE  
33 - D9 E4 01 - A2 B3 FD 
etc ..
```

And indeed the << zeros make no difference what-so-ever as far as I can see. In fact if we ask DMDE to interpret the run-list it simply ignores the zeros too:

[image]

Reference: https://flatcap.github.io/linux-ntfs/ntfs/concepts/file_record.html

Comment: Wow, this is fantastic. It's awesome that people like you are here! The author of the video never allows the earlier bytes to be visible on screen, but I guess we can calculate them to be `d3 fe` (little-endian) because that makes the rest of the cluster chain fall into place. So, we should expect `d3 fe` to be found earlier up in the header, immediately following `0b 00`.

Comment: Yes, thought about 'reverse calculate' the values but you seemed up to it yourself ;)
Feel free to accept the answer if it actually answered your question.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I have a second example. I read a little bit about sparse runs, but that doesn't appear to be what i have. I posted here: https://superuser.com/questions/1792942/  I'm really grateful for your help!

Comment: Thanks for mentioning DMDE. I hadn't heard of it before, but the product looked promising. I installed the free version and it was able to see files on my volume that Testdisk couldn't see (i think bad sectors are in the middle of the MFT, but i can't prove it yet).

Comment: I use it a lot https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLSL85pYTZnmsObzDWa3huXch_PcqKnQd3. I plan adding some step-by-step recovery guides.